# No STREAMS_ADAPTERS_ODBC environment variable set

Tags: stream, infosphere-spl

On building the following Infosphere streams application I get the error message as quoted below. Please advice.

```
namespace application;

use com.ibm.streams.db::*;

composite DB {

type
        temp1 = tuple<int32 i, rstring dateTime, timestamp time, uint32 secondValue,
            int64 seconds> ;
    graph
        stream<int32 id, rstring fname, rstring lname> MyPersonNamesStream = ODBCSource()
        {
            param
                connection : "ConnncetionSpec" ;
                access : "AccessSpec" ;
                connectionDocument : "/home/streamsadmin/Desktop/connectionDocument.xml" ;
                initDelay : 3 ;
                sleepTime : 6 ;
        }

}
```

I have set the environment variables in my .bashrc

```
export STREAMS_ADAPTERS_ODBC_DB2=1
export STREAMS_ADAPTERS_ODBC_INCPATH=/opt/ibm/db2/V10.1/include/
export STREAMS_ADAPTERS_ODBC_LIBPATH=/opt/ibm/db2/V10.1/lib64/
```

The error message is as below _

```
CDISP0411W WARNING: The error output from the /opt/ibm/InfoSphereStreams/StreamsStudio/workspace/DB/com.ibm.streams.db/com.ibm.streams.db/Common/ODBCLibInfo.pl script is: No STREAMS_ADAPTERS_ODBC environment variable set.  Exactly one environment variable beginning with STREAMS_ADAPTERS_ODBC_ (ending with the database name qualifier) must be set.
.
/opt/ibm/InfoSphereStreams/StreamsStudio/workspace/DB/com.ibm.streams.db/com.ibm.streams.db/ODBCSource/ODBCSource: CDISP0180E ERROR: An error occurred while the operator model was loading. The error is: The following non-zero return code was received from the /opt/ibm/InfoSphereStreams/StreamsStudio/workspace/DB/com.ibm.streams.db/com.ibm.streams.db/Common/ODBCLibInfo.pl script: 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify your `.bashrc` changes have taken:

```
env | grep STREAMS_ADAPTERS_ODBC_
```

If no results, try opening a new terminal session for your `.bashrc` changes to take effect, and confirm with the same command.

Comment: The bashrc changes have been taken and I was able to echo those variables. All were getting set. I set these variables in the Streams Studio env variables as well. So that is not the problem.

Comment: Are you building from the command line terminal where you've confirmed the environment variables? Or are you building using some other tool?

Comment: I am building from the same terminal... The issue might be with the db2 installation. Mostly the lib and include might not be reflecting.